# Keycloak - Tomcat adapter vs mod_auth_openidc, what are the use cases

Tags: javascript, java, tomcat, keycloak, mod-auth-openidc

I'm trying to decide what to use with Keycloak, Tomcat adapter or mod_auth_openidc.  I have a simple example working for both cases but i wonder what is the use case for each of the tools.
My application has a java script front end (a one page application built using EXTJS) running on Apache and a Java REST web services back end running on Tomcat.
I believe using mod_auth_openidc will intercept the requests earlier, before the front end java script executes.  The Tomcat adapter will intercept the back end requests after the java script app makes them.
What would be the most important considerations in choosing one tool over the other?